# i have error when submitted char ( ) in uri

Tags: codeigniter, config

I have data like this shown below

```
CV. MAESTRO GROUP (ABDUL KADIR JAELANI)
```

and when I send it to the URI, I get an error

The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

this is my config

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9 ~%.:\_\=+%\&-';
```

I have changed config to

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9 ~%.:\_\=+%\&-()';
```

but it's still an error, can someone help me?

Comment: first thing this is the bad practice to send special char in uri,

Comment: beside the fact that you should use `urlencode` or something like that - i don't see any problems - maybe you use multiple environment dependent config files and you aren't aware of that ? (take a look at your `application/config` folder - are there any environment specific folder ?)

Answer (score 0):

First: This is a bad practice and you should avoid it.

[image]

But if "YOU FULLY UNDERSTAND THE REPERCUSSIONS" try the below. Goodluck

```
]a-z 0-9~%.:[_\-,;&()@!
```

If this doesn't work then most likely you're using a different config file. You can test this by removing the content of permitted_uri_chars.

Comment: Are you sure it's the parentheses causing this problem? Post the URL here